# Search (and Relocate) Rows with Condition

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to search and export (sorted) rows from one worksheet to another one?

I have a Worksheet which is storing a list of rows.

I need to search and export (sorted) rows that contain certain keywords.

For example, "AAA" and "CCC" are the keywords

Worksheet 1 (Original):

```
A             B             C             D
AAA 123       01/mm/yyyy
BBB 456       02/mm/yyyy
CCC 789       03/mm/yyyy
AAA 123       04/mm/yyyy
```

Worksheet 2 (Sorted):

```
A             B             C             D
AAA 123       01/mm/yyyy
AAA 123       04/mm/yyyy
CCC 789       03/mm/yyyy
```

ps: Rows that contain "123" will be grouped together

Any help would be much appreaciated, Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to achieve this. I'll set out two  of them below. Strictly speaking, you don't need to qualify your references in as many steps as you'll see here but I've done that to aid your understanding. When using two different Workbooks it's essential that Excel always knows exactly which of them you are making reference to

**1. Use the autofilter**

This is by far the quickest method, especially if you have a large data set

```
Sub MoveSpecificRows3()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook, destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet, destinationWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destinationRange As Range, r As Range

    'get your workbooks
    Set sourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C/My Documents/.../myfile.xlsx")

    'get your worksheets
    Set sourceWorksheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set destinationWorksheet = destinationWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'get your ranges
    Set sourceRange = sourceWorksheet.Range("A1:D10")
    Set destinationRange = destinationWorksheet.Range("A1")

    'filter on values and copy/paste them over
    With sourceRange
        .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Columns(2), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=AAA", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=CCC"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destinationRange
        sourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove the filter
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
End Sub
```

**2. Loop through each row in your source workbook**

The setup is the same as above but this time a `For` loop is utilized to check for your conditions on each row

```
Sub MoveSpecificRows2()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook, destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet, destinationWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destinationRange As Range, r As Range

    'get your workbooks
    Set sourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C/My Documents/.../myfile.xlsx")

    'get your worksheets
    Set sourceWorksheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set destinationWorksheet = destinationWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'get your ranges
    Set sourceRange = sourceWorksheet.Range("A1:D10")
    Set destinationRange = destinationWorksheet.Range("A1")

    'sort your data
     With sourceRange
         .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Columns(2), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
     End With        

    'loop through each row in your source workbook and move over when AAA or CCC found
    For Each r In sourceRange.Rows
        Select Case r.Cells(1, 1)
            Case "AAA", "CCC"
                destinationRange.Resize(1, r.Columns.Count).Value = r.Value
                Set destinationRange = destinationRange.Offset(1, 0)
        End Select
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

**Note**, in both cases, if your `destinationWorkbook` will already be open you do not need to use the `Workbooks.Open()` call. Replace that line with this:

```
Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks("myfile.xlsx")
```

**Note 2** I also sorted the data in your `sourceWorkbook` to ensure that any values that are transferred over to the `destinationWorkbook` are also sorted. This assumes you have headers for your data. If not, change the `header` property to `header:=xlNo`.